# WooCommerce Rest API - how to authenticate customers?

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to build mobile application for a already live WooCommerce implementation. I am using their Rest API V2 and things are really going smoothly. I can register a customer, view products and also create orders.

But the only glitch is to authenticate an already registered customer using their userid/email address and password. I should be able to do that with the Rest API - but looks like I couldn't. Do I need some other plugin for that?